# Subsequence using single string

Tags: arrays, string, dynamic-programming

Given a string S with length N. Choose an integer K and two non-empty subsequences A and B of characters of this string, each with length K, such that:

- A=B, i.e. for each valid i, the i-th character in A is the same as
  the i-th character in B.
- Let's denote the indices of characters used to construct A by
  a1,a2,…,aK, i.e. A=(Sa1,Sa2,…,SaK). Similarly, let's denote the
  indices of characters used to construct B by b1,b2,…,bK.
- If we denote the number of common indices in the sequences a and b by
  M, then M+1≤K.

What is the maximum value of K such that it is possible to find sequences A and B which satisfy the above conditions.

Please give the simplest solution of this problem.I'm not able to proceed on how to solve this.

Comment: What is M in that?

Comment: Cmon man this is an ongoing codechef contest question 

Answer (score 1):

Your ans will be look like this...
find the minimum distance between repeated character and the ans will be total string length - distance .

> for example of "**ababdbbdhfdksl**"
>   minimum distance between repeated character = 1 ( 2 b's in the middle )
>   so ans = length ( 14 ) - 1 = 13

if all are distinct character answer will be 0 .

Answer (score 0):

the question seems to find the duplicate subsequences of max length.
like if the string is **"ababdb"** then answer will be **4**.
because **abab** can be generated two times and at least one index is different.
so approach is 
1. generate all possible subsequences.
2. store and match with the previous one.
3. if any duplicate found we update the max .

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector> 
#include<string>
using namespace std;

vector<string> test;
vector<string>::iterator iter;
int max = 0;
void Sub(string input , string output)
{
    if (input.length() == 0)
    {
        if (output.length() > max)// store only next greater max
        {
            iter = std::find(test.begin(), test.end(), output);
            if (iter != test.end())
            {
                max = output.length();
                return;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }

        test.push_back(output);
        return;
    }
    Sub(input.substr(1), output);
    Sub(input.substr(1), output + input[0]);
}

int main()
{
    string input = "ababdb";
    string output = "";
    Sub(input, output);
    cout << max;
    return 0;
}
```